# Laravel add commas between array elements

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, implode

I have this **"tags" array** and I want to add commas in between the links in my **article.blade.php**. Originally, this is the tags code:

```
<b>Tags:</b> 
@foreach($article->tags as $tag)
    <a href="/tag/'{{ $tag->name }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

I want this result

```
Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3
```

How do I do this so it looks right in an elegant way?

**PS**
Meanwhile I found the solution. Here it is:

#### **[SOLUTION]**

The tags must be pre-defined in the controller(**ArticlesController.php**) here:

```
public function show(Article $article){     
    foreach($article->tags as $tag){
        $tags[]= link_to('tag/'.$tag->name, $tag->name, $tag->name);
    }   
    return view('page.article',compact('article','tags'));
}
```

Next you can leave your **articles.blade.ph**p like this:

```
<b>Tags:</b> 
{!! implode(', ',$tags) !!}
```

Let me know if you can think of something better.

Comment: keep your anchor tag outside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
@foreach($article->tags as $tag)

    {{ $tag }}
    @if (!$loop->last),@endif

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

in article.blade.php:

```
@foreach($article->tags as $tag)
    <a href="/tag/'{{ $tag->name }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
    @if($loop->last)
        .
    @elseif($loop->remaining == 1)
        &nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;
    @elseif(!$loop->first)
        ,&nbsp;
    @endif
@endforeach
```

will include "&" and "." and output: Tag1, Tag2 & Tag3.

Answer (score -1):

```
Tags:
@foreach($article->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tags .= $tag->name . ', '; }}
@endforeach
{!! $tags !!}
```

I think you have to initialize   `$tags`    first...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Laravel said no,no:

 ErrorException in 738b47fc71d167c6de0d1e03eb6984b6 line 18: Undefined variable: tags (View: /home1/carwars/laravel/resources/views/page/article.blade.php)

Comment: **PS** I even added **<?php $tags = array(); ?>** before the loop and the result was the same. So no.

Comment: I would but the idea here is to use the Laravel Active Records and blade functionality, so this means no plain php code is a solution here.

Comment: Why don't you pass your $tags value from your controller?
You could simply do it right?

Comment: Yes this was the solution. However I believe there could be another approach.